# How to remove matplotlib axis from multiple plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple subplots but I cant seem to remove the axis from all of the plots, only one of them. What is the best way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array_list = [np.random.random_integers(0, i, (5,5)).astype(bool) for i in range(10)]

count = 0    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        axes[i, j].imshow(array_list[count], interpolation='nearest')
        count += 1
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off the axis for each subplot. Try the following code and see if it is what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array_list = [np.random.random_integers(0, i, (5,5)).astype(bool) for i in range(10)]

count = 0    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        axes[i, j].imshow(array_list[count], interpolation='nearest')
        count += 1
        axes[i, j].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: ah brilliant, something simple!